# SOA Client extension not working in firefox

Tags: web-services

I used SOA Client extension for test my websevices and see results of webservices, but two days ago I cannot use SOA Client extension in firefox, it doesnt work.
There is any addon for soap webservices like SOA Client in firefox?
I want to see fields in webservices like textbox not xml.